# IPhone SE and getting phone call through a dongle

Tags: iphone

I can't get phone calls through my dongle and headphones.  The dongle charges my phone so I guess it works.  I can play music from my phone through the dongle to my headphones, so I guess the headphones work.

I thinking I am missing a setting.  Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Jim

Comment: Which headphones. What is a dingle? What happens when a phone call comes in?

Comment: Sony earbuds for the headphones.  A dongle is a device that allows the use of charging and headphone use, at the same time, in IPhones where there is no headphone jack

Comment: What particular adapter, (dongle,) are you using? Manufacturer & model number, please.

Comment: Are you *certain* the Sony earbuds are a *headset* and not just a *headphone*?  The former has a microphone and the latter doesn't.  Now, can you expand on what you mean you "can't get phone calls?"  Does the phone just not accept incoming calls or is it that the other person cannot hear you?  Can you hear them?

Comment: Allan: They are in fact earbuds, my bad in miss-labeling them.  They do have a microphone and volume control in the cord.  I have not tried in-coming calls yet, but outgoing calls I can't hear the phone dial and when commented, the sound comes from the phone not the earbuds.  Thanks for the help